# Consider $R[x]$ and let $S$ be the subring generated by $rx$, where $r \in R$ is some non-invertible element. Then $x$ is not integral over $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-dependence

> Consider $R[x]$ and let $S$ be the subring generated by $rx$, where $r \in R$ is some non-invertible element. Then I want to show that $x$ is not integral over $S$

I'm not seeing why this is the case.

Note : Here R is a commutative ring.

Comment: What does it mean for an element to be integral over a sub ring?

Comment: (Since some users removed comments, resulting in a conversation becoming one-sided and impossible to follow, I've removed all comments as a part of that conversation.)

Answer (score 2):

> In the following I suppose that $R$ is a commutative unitary ring and $R[x]$ denotes the polynomial ring in one variable over $R$.

Assume that $x$ is integral over $S=\Bbb Z[rx]$ (I guess this is what the OP means by "the subring generated by $rx$"). Then there exist $a_i\in S$ such that $x^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_ix^i=0$. In fact $a_i=a_i(rx)$, that is, they are polynomials in $rx$. Since $x^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(rx)x^i=0$ the monomial $x^n$ should be cancelled by other monomial of degree $n$ which appears in $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(rx)x^i=0$. Unfortunately all the monomials of degree $n$ of this sum have coefficients multiples of $r$, so the cancellation is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ask you the same question as I asked below. Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: @user119298 As you were already told, a polynomial is zero if and only if its coefficients are zero. So, if $x^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(rx)x^i=0$ then all coefficients of this polynomial must be zero. Let's see how can such a polynomial look like: consider $R=\Bbb Z$ (the ring of integers), $r=2$ and $n=2$. Then you can have, for example, $x^2+[1+3(2x)-20(2x)^2+5(2x)^3]x+[-6-22(2x)+9(2x)^2]=0$. In order to have such an equality all terms in the left hand side must cancel, in particular $x^2$. But if you look careful the coefficients of $x^2$ in the second and third term are multiples of $2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\,\ 1\cdot x^n+f_{n-1}(rx)\,x^{n-1}+\cdots+f_{0}(rx) = 0\,  $ in $\,R[x],\ $ which, reduced mod $\,r$

$\quad \Rightarrow\ \ \color{#c00}1\cdot x^n+\,f_{n-1}(0)\ x^{n-1}\,+\cdots+\,f_{0}(0)\, =\, 0\,$ in $\,(R/rR)[x]$

$\quad \Rightarrow\ \ \color{#c00}1 = 0\ $ in $\,R/rR,\,$ since, by definition, a polynomial $= 0$ iff all coefficients $= 0.$

$\quad \Rightarrow\ \ \color{}1 \in rR,\ $ so $\,r\,$ is invertible in $\,R,\,$ contra hypothesis.

Comment: It is quite funny that so many people here write "Hint" in the beginning of complete solutions. Apart from that: Perfect solution, 1+.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\bar{R} = R / rR$. Then $R[x] / rR[x] \cong \bar{R}[X]$ and the image $\bar{S}$ of $S$ in $\bar{R}[\bar{x}]$ is contained in $\bar{R}$ by assumption.

Suppose $x$ is integral over $S$. Then $X$ is integral over $\bar{S}$. Hence $X$ is integral over $\bar{R}$. The indeterminate $X$ is integral over $\bar{R}$ inside the polynomial ring $\bar{R}[X]$ only when $\bar{R}$ is the zero ring. So $rR = R$ and $r$ is a unit in $R$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $x$ is integral over $S$. Then there is a polynomial $p(X)=x^n+a_1X^{n-1}+...a_n$, with $a_i$ in $S$ such that $p(x)=0$.

But since $a_i$ are in $S$, they are of the form $q_i(rX)$ for some polynomials $q_i$ with integer coefficients.

We get $0=p(x)=x^n+q_1(rx)x^{n-1}+-...+q_{n}(rx)$. The latter is a polynomial in $x$. For it to be zero, the leading term must be zero. But the $x^n$ term is a multiple of $r$, say $rA$ plus $1$. But if $rA+1=0$, then $(-A)r=1$, which implies $r$ is invertible.

Comment: Why must it be so that the leading co-efficient is $0$? I too concocted this proof, but then doubted its correctness. If we believe that $p(x)=0$ iff all its coefficients are zero, then clearly $p$ could never have been zero in the first place as it has a non-zero leading coefficient.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does $R[x]$ mean for you?

Comment: What would be more helpful is if you told me of the definition I should be looking at! That would be very helpful thank you!

Comment: @user119298: just checking that you do mean the "polynomial ring in one variable $x$ with coefficients in $R$".

Comment: @user119298: Dear user, You are missing the fact that the $q_i$ also have powers of $x$ in them, so the leading coeffient of $p$ may not simply be $x^n$.  In fact, in this argument, it is not so much the leading coefficient of $p$ that we want to study, but the coefficient of $x^n$ (which equals $1$ plus some multiplies of $r$, but which must also equal $0$).  Regards,